# What does "did" refer to?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban (2004)* movie, Hagrid is pelting stones on the surface of the river, and says about Malfoy:

> Hagrid: He said Buckbeak was a deadly and dangerous creature...who
> would kill you as soon as look at you.
>
> Hermoine: And then?
>
> Hagrid: And then he asked for the worst, **did** old Lucius.

What does "did" refer to?

Comment: It's a quaint dialectal / rustic "verbal flourish" that doesn't really mean anything (except *maybe* a slight touch of ***emphasis***). Hagrid probably uses lots of "unusual" expressions like this. Centuries ago, even mainstream Anglophones would include extraneous ***did*** in contexts like *And Adam **did eat** the apple that Eve offered to him* (as opposed to today's standard *Adam **ate** the apple*).

Comment: Compare *John hit me* = *He hit me, John* = *He hit me, did John.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Urban people in places like Liverpool and Manchester talk like that now.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: This is a site for *learners*. They won't be well-served by being encouraged to speak like (city) yokels. I'm sure Rowling would never have had Harry or Hermione speak like that - it's *specifically* a "Hagrid" usage in context.

Comment: In explaining what people see in books, we are not at all encouraging them to speak like that! Please don't get me started on the merits (or lack of them) of Rowling.

Comment: So what's your point? That the way some Liverpudlians / Mancunians *still* speak could be described as "quaint dialectal / rustic"? Or that you don't like the way I've characterised their speech, even though what I said was perfectly true?

Comment: [Harry Enfield](https://youtu.be/EIhFwLjsQug?t=79) taking the piss out of Scousers with *I love Spain, **me***, a few decades ago.

Comment: I definitely feel that the way the Hagrid character speaks is stereotypically dialectical; the quaintness is intended by Rowling, I suppose. Lest I be misunderstood, I was just commenting on an impression I had that people think Hagrid's speech is very old-fashioned. It isn't at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be best described as Old World English. I hesitate to imply it is specifically a British way of speaking. A modern rephrasing would be:

" And then old Lucius did ask for the worst "

Comment: Not 'Old World', whatever that may mean. Using a pronoun to start a statement about someone or something, and repeating the verb is very common in some modern regional UK dialects - she was very pretty, was Mary; he'll be very angry, will Dad; he's very tall, is John; it's very slow, is my car.

Comment: " And then old Lucius did ask for the worst " sounds _more_ quaint and 'Olde Worlde' to me!

Comment: Sorry,Old World is a euphemism for the difference in the grammar of spoken language. Modern vs. distant past. And not being British I don't know the current dialects, but the statement does have a British English feel to it.  And based on current or fictional dialect, seeing how the setting is in Great Britain it lends credence to having it spoken that way.

Comment: It's not 'Old world' in that sense; people talk like that right now.